# Visual Basic table object: Get column count of specific row

Tags: vba, excel

I am trying to to copy values from tables from a word document to an excel sheet. I got stuck at reading the values from a table with different numbers of columns per row. E.g. 2nd row has 3 columns, but 1st row only 2 columns. Therefore `.Columns.Count` is 3 and leads to

> index out of bounds

at 1st row.

I think it should be something like this: `.Rows(1).Columns.Count`

but I can't find anything in the online documentations or forums.

This is the (stripped down) code:

```
Set wdDoc = GetObject(wdFileName) ' (path to .docx)

With wdDoc
TableNo = wdDoc.tables.Count
If TableNo = 0 Then
    MsgBox "Word-Dokument enthält keine Tabellen", vbExclamation
End If

' Loop through all tables
For iTable = 1 To TableNo

    With .tables(iTable)

        ' Check if table contains correct headlines
        Dim columnsNo As Integer
        'columnsNo = .Rows(1).Columns.Count ' this it should be but doesnt exist

        For iCol = 1 To .Columns.Count ' this Count returns 3 although 1st row has only 2 columns
            If (.cell(1, iCol) = sAlias) Then
                containsAlias = True
            End If
        Next iCol
    End With
Next iTable
End With

Set wdDoc = Nothing
```

I hope the code is clear enough, pasting to stackoverflow fcks up the white spaces. Thanks for your help.

Comment: *pasting to stackoverflow fcks up the white spaces* - select the code in the VBE, press TAB to indent 4 spaces evenly, copy, paste into your SO question, done. Or, paste into your SO question, select the code, press Ctrl+K to indent 4 spaces evenly, done. See [editing help](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help) for all the secrets of markdown formatting.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After taking a second look on it on another day, I found the solution myself. To get the number of columns (= number of cells) in a specific row from a  [Table object (Word)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/word-vba/articles/table-object-word), you can use

```
.Rows(1).Cells.Count
```

Seems pretty obvious now that I found it.